# Making this code work in asp.net mvc3 (currently using php)

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a bit stuck on the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable('../examples_support/editable_ajax.php', {
        "callback": function (sValue, y) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
            oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
        },
        "submitdata": function (value, settings) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "14px"
    });
});
```

notice it references '../examples_support/editable_ajax.php', the contents of that php file is:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value'].' (server updated)';
?>
```

I'm stuck on two fronts:

1) how would I convert the code in editable_ajax.php to its equivalent in asp.net?

2) What file do I need to create in asp.net to reference like the php code up there is being referenced? I tried creating a regular cs file but I don't think that was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted this is MVC3... first your route (very specific to this particular call)

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Editable Ajax.php", //name
   "/examples_support/editable_ajax.php", //exact match
   new {controller="EditableAjax", action="Index"}
);
```

Then you need an EditableAjaxController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index(string value)
{
    return View(new EditableAjaxViewModel(value));
}
```

The EditableAjaxViewModel:

```
public EditableAjaxViewModel
{
    public string Value{get; set;}
    public EditableAjaxViewModel(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

The `/Views/EditableAjax/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model EditableAjaxViewModel
@Model.Value <text> (server updated)</text>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, what is EditableAjaxViewModel? Also there is no AddRoute() function in routes (I assume you mean in Global.asax.cs), I used routes.MapRoute if that's ok?

Comment: EditableAjaxModel is just a class to encapsulate the data you are passing to your view. It's just a string now, but you could add other fields to it for other data. MapRoute is right, I think. Sorry about that typo!